# "NoneType" AttributeError in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, attributeerror, nonetype, kivymd

Error That my code is producing
[image: error]
I'm trying to build a screen which would use camera in most of the part and labels in the other. I'm using Camera widget inside a FloatLayout. But the Camera isn't working and is throwing a NoneType error. I've just included the main part of the code and what's really causing the error.
I tried reading the documentation and also researched about some external libraries that i thought i might not be importing by mistake but no luck there. Any help?
Thanks.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
screen_helper = """
<HomeScreen>:
    name: "home"
    MDToolbar:
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "Demo"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: root.nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
        right_action_items: [["face", lambda x: app.ShowProfile()]]
    FloatLayout:
        Camera:
            resolution: (100,120)
            size: self.size
            allow_stretch: True
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        MDLabel:
            text: 'item1:'
        MDLabel:
            text: 'item2:'
        MDLabel:
            text: 'item3'
        MDLabel:
            text: 'item4'
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'Start Scanning'
            on_release:
                app.ShowCamera()

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='home'))

"""


class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen
     def ShowProfile(self):
        self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = 'profile'

    def ShowHome(self):
        self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = 'home'

    def ShowCamera(self):
        self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = 'camera'

DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: At which line was the error?

Comment: From what I could gather after observing, its at: FloatLayout: Camera. Not exactly at this line but i think its related to opencv.py. Please refer to the image I just attached

Comment: Well at screen_helper *6th line* you don't assign a value and you have 3 double quotes which starts a long comment, and you end it with 3 single quotes which should end the comment if you started it with double quotes not single which I believe caused your error

Comment: Sorry, that's not supposed to be a comment. It was a typing mistake that I might've done. This is how helper strings are defined. I've edited it now.

Comment: Please refer to the Image link that I've attached right at the start